# Find a part of field using ADODB.Recordset in vb6

Tags: vb6, filter, find, ado, adodb

I have a table in mdb with field address, which will contain street address e.t.c as string.
I want to be able to search part of this record.

```
 sCriteria = "address like " & "'" & streetAddr & "'"

   Rs1.Filter = sCriteria
```

it searches for e.g "Mall" while there is a record "Mall Road" which should have been found but is not as Road is missing, what should i do to make part of field searchable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
sCriteria = "address like '*" & Quote(streetAddr) & "*'"
```

where `Quote` does a simple `Replace(sText, "'", "''")`

Answer (score 0):

Put an '*' before the closing single-quote, after the filter value.